# Finding expired data in aws dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I have a requirement where I need to store some data in dynamo-db with a status and a timestamp. Eg. `<START, 20180203073000>`

Now, above status flips to `STOP` when I receive a message in SQS. But, to make my system error-proof, I need some mechanism through which I can identify whether a data having `START` status present in dynamo-db is older than 1 day then set it's status to `STOP`. So that, it may not wait indefinitly for the message to arrive from SQS.

Is there an aws feature which I can use to achieve this, without polling for data at regular interval ?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will fit your needs, but here is one possibility:

1. [Enable TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html) on your DynamoDB table. This will work if your timestamp
   data attribute is a Number data type containing time in epoch
   format. Once the timestamp expires, the corresponding item is
   deleted from the table in the background.
2. [Enable Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) on your DynamoDB table. Items that are deleted by TTL
   will be sent to the stream.
3. [Create Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) that connects DynamoDB stream to Lambda function. In your case the 
   trigger will receive your entire deleted item.
4. Modify your record (set 'START' to 'STOP'), remove your timestamp attribute (items with no TTL attribute are not deleted) and re-insert into the table.

This way you will avoid the table scans searching for expired items, but on other side there might be cost associated with lambda execution.

Comment: But as I believe, "DELETE" event in aws may take upto 48 hours.

Comment: Unfortunately this is true. As a workaround AWS recommends using filters when querying the data so that you don't get expired items in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a GSI using the status as primary key and timestamp as sort key. When querying for expired items, use a condition expression like `status = "START" and timestamp < 1-day-ago`.

Be careful though, because this basically creates 2 hot partitions (START and STOP), so make sure the projection expression only has the data you need and no more.

If you have a field that's set on the `status = START` state but doesn't exist otherwise, you'd be able to take advantage of a [sparse index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html) (basically, DynamoDB won't index any items in a GSI if the GSI keys don't exist on the item, so you don't need to filter them on query)